# Handling UDP packets in a queue or on every received packet

Tags: c#

I have a UDP "server" that receives UDP packets and handles them.

The way I have implemented it now, I raise an event whenever I receive a packet, and handling each packet on some threadpool thread. The handling is fairly simple, and I suspect it is much faster than the rate of packets coming in.

I now have another application in which the rate of packets can be higher, and I was wondering whether it would be better in general to have a queue of packets, and handle the packets in a more bulk sort of way, instead of raising the event on every receive.

Do you have any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: might be better to ask specifically what other servers do, rather than solicit opinion

Comment: Just currious why you are using UDP for this? Is you application tolerant of packets being dropped? UDP is not a reliable protocol like TCP/IP is. So, if you are going to queue up packets for processing then this implies that you application is not tolerant of dropped packets. E.g. UDP is used for multimedia streaming where a dropped packet is not a big problem.

Comment: Yes. I know how UDP works. This is more a question of how the resources of handling the packets are best used.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are expecting lot of packets then it might not be a very good option to handle each packet in a new thread. You can make a Producer/Consumer system. Your UDP packet receive module will be producer which will produce the packets (push in some sort of queue) and then you can have a consumer which reads the packet and process it. This will be faster and more scalable option and you can run more than one consumer threads for processing the packets.

It is always better to handle packets in bulk sort of way if you can.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what thread pool threads are there for? Thread pool threads are reused and not created anew for each work item. If more threads are required than currently available, the work items will be *enqueued* until threads become available. And the number of available thread pool threads is always adjusted to the number of CPUs/cores your system has available.

Comment: Yes the thread-pool in this case will keep a cap on total number of threads and it will be adjusted automatically. That's why I didn't highlighted the issue of running out of threads. However in my point of view making this solution in Producer/Consumer way is better instead of firing event for each packet and handling it. This gives you better control.